# Javascript 2D Array Sort Descending Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following 2D Array Values:

```
A   65
B   7
C   775,259
D   893
E   97
F   92,260
G   77,364
H   7,722
I   9,240
J   789,212
```

I wanted to sort by the second column in descending order in which I have written a custom sort function:

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
  return b[1] - a[1];
});
```

The results seem to be sorted in order... but in a character comparison matter. The results are:

```
E   97
I   9,240
F   92,260
D   893
J   789,212
C   775,259
G   77,364
H   7,722
B   7
A   65
```

I know it's sorting, but not the in the way I want to. I've tried typecasting the values into numbers to make sure, but I still get the same results. I want it sorted in descending order by numerical value. Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the data is still in string format. So, you might want to strip the commas and convert the string data to integers like this

```
array.sort(function(a,b) {
  return parseInt(b[1].replace(",", "")) - parseInt(a[1].replace(",", ""));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was able to get it to do what I wanted by parsing it with the Number() function.